# Why are anonymous methods not supported in .Net 1.1?

Tags: .net, delegates, compatibility, il

I've been learning a lot about IL recently with my new job. I have a question though that I can't quite find an answer for.

All of the documentation I've seen indicates that anonymous methods(for use in delegates) isn't supported on .Net 1.1. However, in the IL, anonymous methods appears to be implemented by just using regular methods with "impossible" names.

So what about anonymous methods makes them unsupported on .Net 1.1? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Could you point to the documentation you're talking about?

Comment: I know there is no such thing as a dumb question, but this is like asking why you can't run your horse and cart on gasoline, because your more modern transport does.

Comment: @svick http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163682.aspx#S5 or just go to google and type in `anonymous methods .net 2.0`.... and the C# compiler won't let you create anonymous methods when targetting .Net 1.1.

Comment: @Evildonald No, it's more like if there was a new type of gasoline to come out that for some reason arbitrarily was documented won't work in old cars, yet it's exactly the same.

Comment: @Earlz That doesn't talk about .Net 2.0, it talks about C# 2.0. And it's certainly true that anonymous methods were new in C# 2.0. Versions of .Net and C# are closely related, but still different.

Answer (score 4):

> So what about anonymous methods makes them unsupported on .Net 1.1? Is there something I'm missing?

The compilers that target .Net 1.1 did not support this, so there was no way to create one in the 1.1 version of the Framework.

A custom language or compiler could, of course, make a version of anonymous methods - but nothing did at the time.

Comment: Ah... that's what I was thinking, but it didn't make any sense to me as to why they wouldn't go backwards and add support to .Net 1.1 targets for such a thing

Comment: @Earlz .NET 2 was such a huge change (with generics, etc) that I don't think there was much desire to go do anything with 1.1 after it came out...

Comment: It seems then like anonymous methods isn't anything new to .Net 2.0, but rather new to the C# compiler(whatever version tied to .Net 2.0).. They've went backwards plenty before. You can compile things using the C# 4.0 compiler, that targets .Net 2.0. Of course, only language features are supported, and not framework features... My question is why anonymous methods are classified as a framework feature, but really a language feature

Comment: @Earlz They're not a framework feature - they're a language feature.  The documentation you're quoting is just not clear on it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the documentation is misleading.  What it should state is that anonymous methods are not supported in early versions of the managed languages (VB, C#, C++/CLI).

As you have discovered, there is no notion of an anonymous method in IL; it is up to the language to make them anonymous (by hiding them with mangled names).